Alexa App only linking with authorization code grant, need to redirect user back to alexa app when user click deny on consent
I am implementing custom OAuth page which can be opened by url mentioned in authorization uri that we specify in alexa developer console.
In Alexa-app-only flow (browser flow) account linking, when user doesn't want to continue the login flow  (Like In my case the consent page is shown before user logs-in and user click deny on consent ): is there any redirect uri that I can call in my OAuth Page UI, so that I will redirect user back to alexa app.
In my authorization UI, when I click on deny, I'm using window.close() Javascript method to close the window which gets user back to enable skill page in Android phone alexa app (assuming Chrome as default browser), but when the default browser changes to Firefox, for Safari or iOS alexa app, window.close() is not closing the window and not getting user back to alexa app (enable skill page).
So, I thought my approach of closing window wrong, now I'm trying to find a solution in terms of redirect uri that alexa provides to redirect user back to enable skill page of alexa.
